# Suggestions for creating 3D Bounding Boxes of Books on a Shelf from RGB-D Images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, opencv, reference-implementation

I am new to image processing, so I beg your pardon if this is a trivial question. I am trying to use an RGB-D camera to detect 3D bounding boxes of books on a shelf.
Here are some examples of possible scenarios: [books on a shelf 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRQHM.jpg) or [books on a shelf 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07BG2.jpg). I would like to infer the dimensions (length, width and height) and the pose of each book and of the shelf. So approximate each of the element in the scene with a 3D bounding box.

I would like to get suggestions on which computer vision or image processing techniques are best suited to implement a solution to my problem. I am thinking of YOLO 5 or the following paper:

> Deng, Z. and Jan Latecki, L., 2017. Amodal detection of 3d objects: Inferring 3d bounding boxes from 2d ones in rgb-depth images. In Proceedings of the IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (pp. 5762-5770).

Are there any better or easier alternatives or already implemented packages?

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1):

Exploiting the 3D geometry is important here. From the depth image, you could get the 3D point cloud by [backprojection](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html). Once the point cloud (set of 3D points) is given, you might benefit from VoteNet:

> Deep Hough Voting for 3D Object Detection in Point Clouds, Charles R.
> Qi, Or Litany, Kaiming He, Leonidas J. Guibas, ICCV 2019
> https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09664

If, in addition, the color (RGB) information is available, we could utilize within the same framework, this time maybe using ImVoteNet:

> ImVoteNet: Boosting 3D Object Detection in Point Clouds with Image
> Votes, Charles R. Qi, Xinlei Chen, Or Litany, Leonidas J.
> Guibas, CVPR 2020
> https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.10692

Both of the papers provide open source implementations. See [here for VoteNet](https://github.com/facebookresearch/votenet) and [this repository for ImVoteNet](https://github.com/facebookresearch/imvotenet). Note that both of these are methods that require heavy *supervision*, i.e. large amounts of annotated training data. If such data is not available at your disposal, I would start looking into hand-crafted algorithms, e.g. descriptors or point pair feature detectors.

Hope this helps.